# AvalonDock 1.3 Theme ArgumentException in Designer (UnsetValue)

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, avalondock

I'm currently developing one of my first WPF applications (I'm comming from WindowsForms development). As MDI framework I'm using AvalonDock version 1.3. I tried to set the [`ExpressionDark`](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version1.3/AvalonDock.Themes/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml) theme on AvalonDock from `App.XAML` as a `ResourceDictionary` in `MergedDictionaries` :

```
<Application x:Class="Application.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Application"
             StartupUri="View/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ExpressionDark.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources> 
</Application>
```

After I've set this the designer doesn't work anymore. It displays the following Exception:

> ArgumentException: "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" ist kein gültiger
>   Wert für die Eigenschaft "System.Windows.Controls.Image.Source" auf
>   einem "Setter".

This roughly translates to:

> ArgumentException: "{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}" is not a valid
>   value for the property "System.Windows.Controls.Image.Source" on a
>   "Setter".

The application compiles and runs without problems and the theme is set correctly, but working in the designer is not possible any longer. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
The problem also occurs if the [`ExpressionDark.XAML`](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version1.3/AvalonDock.Themes/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml) is the only ResourceDictionary:

```
<Application x:Class="Application.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Application"
             StartupUri="View/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ExpressionDark.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources> 
</Application>
```

Comment: I think we need to see the contents of ExpressionDark.XAML

Comment: @NH. I've inserted links to the codeplex source of the XAML file